# Android Multiple Swipe Views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Recently I've been trying to create an advanced look and feel for my apps by implementing multiple swipe views to it.

Let me explain what I mean by "multiple swipe view":

[image: Amazingly drawn demonstration of my goal]

And please excuse my poor Paint skills.

As you can see I'm simply trying to stack swipe-views under each other. Each swipe-view contains different fragments of course.

I successfully created one swipe view but that's all I've managed to do.
To create one swipe-View I created PagerAdapter class that extends from FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment; 
        switch(i){
        case 0:
             fragment = new MyFragment1();
             break;
        case 1:
             fragment = new MyFragment2();
             break;
        case 2:
             fragment = new MyFragment3();
             break;
        default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid section number");
        }

        return fragment;
    }}
```

The class named "MyFragment1/2/3" is a class that creates a view with the correct layout:

```
    public static class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simpletab, null);
        return v;
}
}
```

I created a ViewPager and a SectionsPagerAdapter.

```
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
```

Also, in the onCreate function of the MainActivity I added:

```
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.comp);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

And that gives me the swipe-view.
Now I tried to make two of them so I wrote another PagerAdapter class that initiate different fragment. I also created a new ViewPager and defined it as I did for the first one:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
OtherSectionsPagerAdapter OtherPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;
ViewPager OtherViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    //final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    OtherPagerAdapter = new OtherSectionsPagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.comp);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    OtherViewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ScreenPager);
    OtherViewPager.setAdapter(OtherPagerAdapter);
```

This is my main_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScreenPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    app:context=".MainActivity" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/comp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    app:context=".MainActivity" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager></LinearLayout>
```

And if I'm trying to run the app, it crashes.
What am I doing wrong and could you please point me to the right way?

EDIT:
Here is the logcat that I get after crashing:

```
    09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid section number
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at com.example.casio.MainActivity$compSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(MainActivity.java:707)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1048)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 16:56:14.283: E/AndroidRuntime(8816):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid section number
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at com.example.casio.MainActivity$compSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(MainActivity.java:707)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1048)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 17:58:20.469: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your Logcat that generate after Crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete these lines from your both ViewPagers.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: Thanks!
Doing this and also adjusting the number of sections i have to match the number of fragments cases in the getItem() function fixed this!